# Определение объектов и расстояние между ними

Tags: c#, python, opencv

[image: Фото с камеры]1. Необходимо определить расстояние между центрами рулонов (пусть будут два самых ближних к камере).

2. Необходимо найти их контуры.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста как реализовать, а то идеи закончились.

пытался выделить именно ленту, приводил к чернобелому изображению, но как выделить сами рулоны не знаю. (приводил к ч/б 2 разными способами)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если идеи закончились, значит они все-таки были? Если вы их добавите в вопрос, то поможете другим участникам, чтобы они не делали еще раз то, что вам не подошло.

Comment: Мало данных. В чем расстояние в, в пикселях ? Задача тянет на нормальный такой бюджет.

Comment: Возможно, что Вам подскажет решение ключевые слова - векторизация растрового изображения. В Вашем случае задача упрощается, Вам нужно искать контуры цилиндров. Больше сейчас я ничего не подскажу - давно этим не занимался.

Comment: [Нам понадобится команда и пять лет на исследования.](https://xkcd.ru/i/1425_v1.png)